# Cannot find GENYMOTION path after installed it (windows, Android Studio 4.0.1)

Tags: android, genymotion

I would like to use GenyMotion as the Android Studio emulator.
I installed GenyMotion plugin successfully but when I  need to configure it - to find the path where
GenyMotion installed - i cannot find it on my PC.

what am I doing wrong?

thank you

Comment: What do you want to do? When you run a device from GenyMotion, Android studio will automatically recognize it. There is no further action required.

Comment: I am new to Android Studio /Flutter.
As I read, in order to use the GenyMontion as the Emulator I need to configure it and to select the path where GenyMontion installed on my machine.
I installed it, but cannot find it.

also there is a warning in Android Studio saying:
You must specify the path to the Genymotion folder to use this feature

Comment: What path did you set?